# Wait until Retrofit enque will be executed

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, retrofit2

I have async call to server with this structure:

```
AuthAPI authAPI = retrofitService.getRetrofit().create(AuthAPI.class);

authAPI.registerUser(requestBody)
    .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call,
            @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            // Response processing.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call,
            @NonNull Throwable t) {
            // Failure processing.
        }
    });
```

This code is executed inside `onClick()` method of a button. After this code a new Fragment is replacing the current, but when this code executes due to `.enqueue()` is async the async part is not finished yet, so application is crashing. So, I need to wait until async code is executed and then show new fragment.

I could use `execute()` method instead of `enqueue()` method, but if I understand it right, until `execute()` method is finished the whole UI thread will be frozen and ProgressBar animation will not run. That is also bad for me.

So, what I am asking is, how could I wait for server response to be processed and dont lock my UI-thread so ProgressBar was spinning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should show some Progressbar before starting, then hide it in the `onResponse`, and after that, you can show your fragment, here is some code:

```java
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
authAPI.registerUser(requestBody).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call,
                           @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        // Response processing.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide progress bar when response is received
                
                // Replace the current fragment with the new fragment here
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                NewFragment newFragment = new NewFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call,
                          @NonNull Throwable t) {
        // Failure processing.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide progress bar when response fails
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The reason for using `runOnUiThread` is to ensure the View Updates and fragment transaction will happen on the main UI thread and not on the background thread that the `enqueue` operation works on, so it doesn't raise an exception!

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever wait for an async function to finish on the main thread.  Doing so will at best make your app freeze and be unresponsive, at worst cause an ANR and crash.  Instead, anything you want to do after the async code should be put in the async callback- in the onResponse or onFailure block.